# C++ using char in an if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, char

I'm building a standard four-function calculator and I've come across a confusing bug.

```
char Engine::AskUser(){
    char type;
    std::cout << "'a'dd, 'm'ulitply, 's'ubract, or 'd'ivide ?\n";
    std::cin >> type;
    CheckUser(type);
    return type;
}

void Engine::CheckUser(char uType){
    if(uType != 'a' || uType != 's' || uType != 'm' || uType != 'd'){
        std::cout << "Type 'a', 'm', 's', or 'd'\n";
        AskUser();
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

What happens is, even if I enter a, s, m, or d, the `if` statement still iterates as if those conditions were true, which is clearly not the case. I don't get it. Is uType not carrying the value of type from AskUser(), or something similar?

Answer (score 8):

```
if(uType != 'a' || uType != 's' || uType != 'm' || uType != 'd')
```

A `char` is either not equal to `'a'`, or it is equal to `'a'`, in which case it's not equal to `'s'`, so this condition is always true.

It should be logical AND:

```
if(uType != 'a' && uType != 's' && uType != 'm' && uType != 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

your if conditional is doing the following check:

if value is not equal to a -- 
or 
if value is not equal to s --
or
if value is not equal to m --
or
if value is not equal to d --

regardless of what char variable uType is, it will always NOT BE at least 3 of the previous 4 variables, hence the if conditional will always result in a TRUE value.

Edited: What I believe you wanted to do was the following:

```
if ( (uType == 'a') || (uType == 's') || ......)
{
    return;
}
else
{
   ...//The code you previously had if it were true
}
```

In this case, you would return whenever uType was 1 of the 4 values, otherwise you would implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line -

```
if(uType != 'a' || uType != 's' || uType != 'm' || uType != 'd')
```

to  this -

```
if(uType != 'a' && uType != 's' && uType != 'm' && uType != 'd')
```

It will surely work.